# IBM Worklight J2ME Timeout

Tags: java-me, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have build a J2ME application by using IBM Worklight 6.1. After request time out which is default 30 seconds while invoking the procedure two request are going . Does any one have an idea how to increase the time out for J2ME ..

Answer (score 0):

After some asking around, according to developers of JavaME support in Worklight, the answer is "no". In Worklight-based applications for JavaME, a procedure request timeout option is not available.